# Delete particular data in mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

How can I delete particular data in mongodb using node.js ?

```
router.post('/deletedata', (req, res) => {
console.log("deleted values are",req.body.id)
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
         var dbo = db.db("mohan");
         var myquery = req.body.id;
         console.log("myquery value is:", myquery)
        dbo.collection("customers").remove({myquery}, function(err, obj) {
          if (err) throw err;
          db.close();
        });
      });

    res.json({
        statusCode: 200,
        result: "success",
    })
}
);

export default router;
```

I got particular id from React hooks crud app , So i can see  the id in node js but it does not delete the that particular id data in mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Your query will only delete documents with `myquery: passedId`

I bet query should look like `{_id: myquery}`

```
dbo.collection("customers").remove({_id: myquery}, function(err, obj) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: If I use this code its working but deleting top of the value in collection. But i need to delete what I actually clicked id (delete button in crud app in hooks).

Answer (score 0):

```
dbo.collection("customers").remove(myquery, function(err, obj) {
 if (err) throw err;
 db.close();
});
```

Comment: In my hooks using axios like this..const deleteUser = id => {
  console.log("id value is",id)
  setEditing(false)
  setUsers(users.filter(user => user.id !== id))
  //let data = id 
  axios.post('http://localhost:8001/api/social/deletedata',id)
  .then((res) => {
   console.log('response',res);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
   console.log('error block called',error);
  })
 }

Comment: Give any example which run by using react hooks with nodeJS and mongoDB. That should be a crud Application. I'm lacking in delete and update operation with back end

Comment: If you are getting an id in node side which you have to remove from MongoDB then above query must work.. and if you are not getting the id in node side then you have to access as req.params.id and not req.body.id.

Comment: Yes I got a delete id from react hooks crud but in mongodb data cant remove  wat to do..Give any solution and above query didnt work

Comment: For above query to work id must be a ObjectId. if its not then simply use {_id: myquery}

Comment: in node js any needs to create structure like for client side input fields?

Answer (score 0):

try using `delete({query})` or `deleteMany({query})`

Comment: as deleteMany delete multiple record by matching query

Comment: can you post what is the data in your collection